# Why Ubuntu 18.04 use `/sbin/init` instead of `systemd`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, init

First of all, Here is my environment of system:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-52-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-051) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 22:49:08 UTC 2019

# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Refer to this [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), ubuntu has used Systemd by default since 15.04 and Systemd runs with PID 1 as `/sbin/init`. However, I found the different result on my ubuntu 18.04:

```
# ps aux | awk '$2==1{print $0}'
root         1  0.0  0.8 159692  8784 ?        Ss   Oct24   0:21 /sbin/init noibrs splash

# lsof -p 1 | grep txt
systemd   1 root  txt       REG              252,1  1595792     927033 /lib/systemd/systemd
```

So, my question is that:

1. Why Ubuntu 18.04 use `/sbin/init` instead of `/lib/systemd/systemd`?
2. Why `lsof -p 1 | grep txt` return `/lib/systemd/systemd` while the process of PID 1 is `/sbin/init`?

Comment: ...and here come the down voters despite being a decent question and accurate answer because it's not strictly a "programming question". Instead they could recommend it be moved to a more appropriate site. Never mind if the poster has an account there or not, that's of little concern to the SE pedants... (eye roll)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/sbin/init` is a symbolic link to `/lib/systemd/systemd`

Take a look at the output of `stat /sbin/init` or `readlink /sbin/init`

This is what they mean by systemd "running as /sbin/init". The systemd binary is linked as `/sbin/init` and started by that link name.

**Update**

To further explain the difference between the `ps` and `lsof` output: `ps` is showing the command that started the process, while `lsof` is showing which files a process has opened.

When systemd was started, it was called by `/sbin/init noibrs splash`, the file system resolved the link to the file `/lib/systemd/systemd` which was then read from disk and executed.